# Steering wheel feels loose without any play

Tags: suspension, power-steering, steering-wheel

I was driving a car and took a sharp bend ( about 80° ) around 40kmph. Suddenly the steering wheel over steered. It was like some external force pushed the rack. Since I was driving slow I was able to take it back to the lane and stop the vehicle.

Ever since then, the steering wheel feels loose/light. It does not have any play. Steering wheel is still in correct position when driving straight. Also it does not wobble. A mechanic checked it and told that there's no issue. And he told that, it could be the steering motor and told me to not to worry about it that much.

---

Here is the dash cam record.(video speed is x0.5) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WkLa2j3RSKNhfMbEXoLf0eqOvk1-WG4U/view?usp=sharing

In the video, at 0.02 timestamp, the steering wheel over steered and then I turned the steering wheel to opposite side to take it back to the lane.

---

Recent repairs

1. Brake caliper pins replaced
2. Lower arms replaced
3. Steering rack with tie rods replaced
4. Done a wheel alignment and balance
5. One outer CV joint replaced
6. New tires ( Only done about 15000km )
7. All shocks were replaced 2 years ago

Car details
2010 Alto LXI ( Indian version )

Even though the mechanic said that don't worry about it I do not feel confident enough to drive this car. It feels loose, It could again oversteer & could easily lead to an accident. I went to the best mechanic shop in the area. I have to drive longer distance to go to another reputed shop and I do not want to drive this without having any idea why this happens.

So i would really appreciate any help to diagnose this issue.

Comment: This vehicle has electric power steering?

Comment: Hi. Yes it has electric power steering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said there was a change and you have reserves about driving it safely. This means it's definitely something to worry about. You absolutely need a second opinion. Considering the recent work I would first check for a loose steering rack or control arm. These could cause your problem. With your symptoms something is loose or worn. It should not be difficult to figure it out. The electric motor would typically throw a code and illuminate the check engine light if it was faulty, but if there definitely isn't any mechanical problems it should be looked at by someone capable of diagnosing the motor. Maybe a dealer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try you suggestions tomorrow and give you an update

Comment: It was the lower arm. Apparently one of the lower arm I installed was damaged. Replaced both arms and did a wheel alignment. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

At 0:02 you drive over the darker patch on the road (visible at 0:00 in the middle-right portion of your footage).

I assume that your tires are "narrow", which means they can "grab" onto any "tracks" in the road (more easily).

Are you sure that your tires just didn't "grab" a track and "pull" you along?
If the mechanic says the car is fine, confirm that the road didn't make your tires pull your car. I think the damaged road just pulled your verhicle to the right.

External forces on your steering usually just means influence from the road itself onto your wheel(s).